# Centos 7. Package is intended for a different architecture в yum update. Как исправить?

Tags: linux, centos7, yum

ОСь: Centos 7.6.1810
Текущее ядро: 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64

Чистая система,свежеустановленная.

При попытке сделать yum update после проверки пакетов получаю следующее
[image: error]

Судя по всему проблема в том что в списке присутствуют пакеты noarch. Но как они туда попали и как исправить эту ошибку?
Кто нибудь сталкивался? Спасибо заранее

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса вывод команды `$ uname -a; rpm --showrc | grep -i arch`

Comment: Вам надо  использовать данную команду для фикса: ``rpm -ivh ...``, указав, соотвественно, полный путь к этим самим .noarch пакетам. See ``man rpm`` for more information.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ``| grep -i arch`` = x86_64)))